# If all finite space with discrete metric is complete, what about the infinite case?

Tags: real-analysis

So finite metric space with the discrete metric is complete because any Cauchy sequence will eventually be constant and so will converge at that point which is in the set. But why is the same argument not correct for the infinite space with the same discrete metric?

Comment: I think you're confusing two properties. Every discrete metric space is complete (you gave the proof in your post). But finite metric spaces are compact, while infinite discrete metric spaces are not compact.